Mips I-type instructions - Q about machine to assmebly code
I wanted to ask about how to read machine code as assembly code. I have only done convertions that looks for example like this
001000 00001 00000 0000000000000100   -- addi $r0, $r1, 0x0004

or R-type instruction like this
000000 00000 00001 00010 00000 100000 -- add  $r2, $r0, $r1.

But now I've come across some instructions that looks like this
001000 10001 10000 0000000000000101   -- addi $s0, $s1, 5

and
001000 10011 01000 1111111111110100   -- addi $t0, $s3, –12.

I know that for addi instruction it is addi target_reg, source_reg, imm and I assume they write $t and $s here because it is the target and source reg, but I don't understand why they are red differently then the once I gave example on first.
If I would have red the machine code for the lw instruction for example, I would have written it as
addi $t16, $s17, 5

and
addi $t8, $s19, -12.

Could someone help me understand what is wrong with this way of converting these code snippets where it is not wrong in my first examples.
EDIT I got a link about MIPS Assembly/Register file, and I found out that the t and s (and other letters) stood for a range of specific registers, for example $t is registers number 24 and 25.
I understand why it is displayed in such way!

Where did you come up with $s19? The $s registers go from $s0 to $s8.

Ooh I missunderstood the t and s then. I'll make an update about this!
And I dont know where 19 came from... I see now that it is wrong, but i shouldve written 35...

Where did you get 35? MIPS has only 32 registers. There is no register 35.

Yes I know, i dont understand tho how, from the machine code, i can read that the source register should be $s3 and the target register should be $t0.

In 001000 10001 10000 0000000000000101, the source register is 10001 which is $17. The destination is 10000 which is $16. So the instruction is addi $16, $17, 5. According to the linked table, an alternate name for $16 is $s0 and an alternate name for $17 is $s1. The alternate names are far more popular than the ISA names. Just like how "Gordon Sumner" is more popularly known as "Sting".

Sorry for being so slow... I saw the link you sent me and was just stuck. I understand now how it is written. Thank you very much for your patient, hope you have a good day! :D

First, MIPS doesn't use $rX register numbers.
There are two naming schemes for the registers:

The raw encoding number, which are $0 through $31.

The friendly name, which use a single alpha character followed by a single digit.  These friendly names help us choose register by usage & calling convention.

The alpha characters are (mostly) v, a, t, s

v stands for value, meaning function return value
a stands for argument, here meaning actual argument for function calling\
t stands for temporary, meaning call clobbered
s stands for saved, meaning call preserved





Tip: Never mix raw encoding numbers and friendly register names in the same program — super confusing.  So, just stick with friendly register names.



NAME
NUMBER
USE
PRESERVED ACROSS CALL




$zero
$0
The Constant Value 0
N.A.


$at
$1
Assembler Temporary
No


$v0-$v1
$2-$3
Function Results
No


$a0-$a3
$4-$7
Function Arguments
No


$t0-$t7
$8-$15
Temporaries
No


$s0-$s7
$16-$23
Saved Temporaries
Yes


$t8-$t9
$24-$25
Temporaries
No


$sp
$29
Stack Pointer
Yes


$ra
$31
Return Address
No




For more information see:
https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf
and also study the MIPS calling convention.

For the I-Type instructions, the rs and rt field orderings are reversed in machine code vs. assembly language.  Similar is true for the R-Type instructions.
Refer to the table BASIC INSTRUCTION FORMATS, and also the OPERATION (in Verilog) column of the CORE INSTRUCTION SET.  The former shows the machine code fields for the various formats, while the latter shows how each individual instruction uses those fields.
Nothing in that green sheet refers to the assembly syntax for the instructions, but as mentioned above, I-Type uses "opcode rt, rs, imm" while R-Type uses "opcode rd, rs, rt".  Note that these (rs, rt, rd) are machine code field names (which are used to hold register numbers) they are not themselves register names.

Oh okey that was a very good sheet, thank you for sharing it! I have a question about the reg name then. You said that the ... rt, rs... is field names. How do you then know what the reg name is? Could you follow up a bit on that.

As I stated register names for MIPS are either strictly numeric, e.g. $10, or alphanumeric, e.g. $a0.  The green sheet will map $a0 to its numeric name, and that number is also the encoding when used in rs rt or rd.
